# npm test command is not running?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Hi everyone I'm beginner in nodejs .I want to test some basic functionality in my code.I m using **JEST** testing framework.In the command prompt I used **npm test** I could not test my code it shows 
**npm ERR! Test failed.** Can anyone solve this issue? Thanks in advance...

```html
lib.test.js:

const lib=require('../lib.js');


describe('absolute',()=>{

    it('It should return positive number if given number is positive',()=>{
        const result=lib.absolute(1);
        expect(result).toBe(1);
    });
    
    it('It should return positive number if given number is negative',()=>{
        const result=lib.absolute(-1);
        expect(result).toBe(1);
    })
    
    it('It should return zero if given number is zero',()=>{
        const result=lib.absolute(0);
        expect(result).toBe(1);
    });

});



lib.js:

// Testing numbers 
module.exports.absolute = function(number) {
  if (number > 0) return number; 
  if (number < 0) return -number; 
  return 0; 
}


package.json:

{
  "name": "testing-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "db.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^22.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing the error you are seeing is

`SecurityError: localStorage is not available for opaque origins`

---

The default [test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) for `Jest` is a browser-like environment provided by `jsdom`, which is required for testing code like React applications that are designed to run in the browser.

If you are going to use `jsdom` as the test environment then you [need to set `testURL` in the `Jest` configuration](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2304), otherwise you will get the error seen above.

If your code is designed to run on `node` and you don't need a browser-like environment then you can set your test environment to be `node`.

The easiest way to do that in your case is to [pass it as a command line argument](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#env-environment) to `jest` in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --env=node"
},
```